# A lottery with two cars

Tags: probability

A Tv Shows organize a lottery with two cars as prizes. Any watcher may send an SMS for participating independently of other watchers. If there are only one or two participants then they get a car. Otherwise, no one wins. What is the probability that any car won?

Suppose there are $n$ watchers, say $1, \cdots, n$. Moreover, assume that person $i$ send an SMS with the probability $p_i$. Then the probability that any car won is: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^np_i\prod_{j\neq i}(1-p_j)+\sum_{i < j}p_ip_j\prod_{k\neq i,j}(1-p_k)$$

Now, I am interested to know when this probability goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: What if $p_I = 0$ for $i > 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time the $p$s are greater than some number $\epsilon$ greater than zero the probability will go to zero.  We have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^np_i\prod_{j\neq i}(1-p_j)+\sum_{i < j}p_ip_j\prod_{k\neq i,j}(1-p_k)\lt n(1-\epsilon)^{n-1}+n^2(1-\epsilon)^{n-2}$$
which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$  If the $p_i$ go to zero fast enough you can have a positive probability even as $n \to \infty$.

Douglas Hofstadter had a piece "Dilemmas for Superrational Thinkers, Leading Up to a Luring Lottery" in the June 1983 [Metamagical Themas (free download)](https://archive.org/details/MetamagicalThemas) like this with just one prize.  It is an interesting essay.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Could you please give a precise example which the probability does not go to zero.

Comment: You just need the product of the $(1-p_i)$ to stay above zero.  You can take the log  and say you need the sum of the $-p_i$ to not go to $-\infty$ so take your favorite  series that converges to a finite number.  $p_i=\frac 1{i^2}$ will work.

Comment: It is a nice argument! Thanks for your time.